# Change the value of a column based on finding characters in another column with python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset that contains columns city and country. Some of the country columns are incorrectly mislabelled as 'Other'. I know this because some of the city values contain labels like saddle lake (Canada). Is there a way I can search a subset of the value in the city to change the value in Country. IE search for any city value containing the word 'Canada' and change country to 'Canada'. I'd like to do this for multiple countries including the USA and UK. which might mean my search would need an 'or' element and search usa, US, USA etc

Current dataset:

```
City - Country
Saddle(Canada) - Other
Dublin - Other
Detroit - USA
Vancouver - Canada
NYC: US - Other
```

Output:

```
Saddle(Canada) - Canada
Dublin -Other
Detroit - USA
Vancouver - Canada
NYC: US - USA
```

Some sample code I tried but this did not work:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['city'].str.contains("anada"):
        df.loc[index, 'country'] = "Canada"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a high-level approach you could try. Depending on how dirty your dataset is, it might be useful, but at the end of the day, this is an NLP/AI problem.

```py
# using regular expressions _may_ make your life easier
import re

# these regex are for entertainment purposes only
# no warranty of efficacy or fitness for any specific purpose is implied
country_patterns = {
  "Canada" : re.compile(r'canada'),
  "USA": re.compile(r'(usa)|(us)|(united states)|(united states of america|america)'),
  "Japan": re.compile(r'(japan)|(nihon)',
   # etc...
}

for index, row in df.iterrows():
   # a double loop now, so we can check each country pattern against the city
   for country, pattern in country_patterns.items()
       # ignoring the case will simplify creating the regular expressions
       if re.match(pattern, row['city'], re.IGNORECASE):
           df.loc[index, 'country'] = country
           # move on to the next row, since we found a match
           break
```

You'll have to create your own regular expressions, and that can become a headache of its own.